# A problem on Riesz Lemma.

Tags: functional-analysis

**Riesz Lemma**: Let $X$ be a normed space. Let $Y$ be a closed proper subspace of $X$ and $Y\neq X$. Let $r$ be a real number such that $0<r<1$. Then there exists some $x_r\in X$ such that
$$||x_r||=1~~\text{and}~~r<dist(x_r,Y)\leq 1.$$.

**Proof**:  Since $Y$ is a proper suspace of $X$,  Let $x\in X\setminus Y$. $X\setminus Y$ is open as $Y$ is closed, this, we have $dist(x,Y)>0$.  Given $r<1$, there exists $y_0\in Y$ such that $||x-y_0||<dist(x,Y)/r$.
Let $x_r=\frac{x-y_0}{||x-y_0||}.$
Then $||x_r||=1$, since $0\in Y$, $dist(x_r,Y)\leq 1$.

Now,
$$dist(x_r,Y)=\frac{dist(x-y_0,Y)}{||x-y_0||}=\frac{dist(x,Y)}{||x-y_0||}>r.$$

I understand the proof of this Lemma.

Problem: Let $X$ be a normed space. The Riesz Lemma with $r=1$ holds in $X$ if and only if for every closed proper subspace $Y$ of $X$, there are $x\in X$ and $y_0\in Y$ such that $||x-y_0||=dist(x,Y)>0$.

Attempt: Suppose Riesz lemma with $r=1$ holds. Then there exist $x_1\in X$ such that
$$||x_1||=dist(x_1,Y)=1.$$
From the above proof of Riesz lemma we can choose $y_0\in Y$ such that
$x_1=\frac{x-y_0}{||x-y_0||}$ this shows that$ ||x_1||=1$. Also $$dist(x_1,Y)=\frac{dist(x,Y)}{||x-y_0||}=1.$$ Thus, $||x-y_0||=dist(x,Y)>0$.

In the converse part, if we take $r\neq 1$, then without loss of generality $r<1$, by Riesz lemma we can find the contradiction.

By the way proof doesn't sound good. What I have tried I put.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: you say you tried many times... can you tell us what exactly you have tried? It might save the people who want to help you some time

Comment: also, this cannot work with $r=1$ as currently stated because of the inequality $r < \dots \leq 1$.

Comment: @supinf this is an exercise problem. I typed my efforts. Have a look ...Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to answer an old question. I am doing this question now.

Riesz lemma: Let $X$ be a NLS and $Y$ be a closed and proper subspace of $X$. Then for every $r\in(0,1)$, there exists $x_r\in X\setminus Y$ such that
$$||x_r||=1,\,r<d(x_r,Y)\leq1$$
Our question: Let $X$ be a NLS. The Riesz Lemma with $r=1$ holds in $X$ iff for every closed proper subspace $Y$ of $X$, there are $x\in X$ and $y_0\in Y$ such that $$||x-y_0||=d(x,Y)>0$$

---

Proof:

$(\Leftarrow)$ Let $Y$ be a closed and proper subspace of $X$. By assumption, there are $x\in X$ and $y_0\in Y$ such that $||x-y_0||=d(x,Y)>0$. Now, let $x_0=\frac{x-y_0}{||x-y_0||}$, so $||x_0||=1$. And, $$d(x_0,Y)=\inf_{y\in Y}||x_0-y||=\inf_{y\in Y}\frac{||x-y_0-(y||x-y_0||)||}{||x-y_0||}=\frac{d(x,Y)}{||x-y_0||}=1$$

$(\Rightarrow)$ Suppose Riesz Lemma holds for $r=1$ and $Y$ be a closed and proper subspace of $X$. By Riesz lemma, there exists $x_1\in X\setminus Y$ such that $||x_1||=1,\,d(x_1,Y)=1$. Let $y_0\in Y$ be arbitrary and $x=x_1+y_0$. Then observe that $||x-y_0||=d(x,Y)=d(x_1,Y)=1>0$